What exactly is "push the car higher back a day"?
This is said by a native english speaker during his visit around New Zealand.

When we booked this train, we contacted our travel agent and was like can you push the car higher cuz we got to pick up another car when we get to Christ Church and we said can you push the car higher back a day because we will not be in a suitable state to pick up the car. Most scenic train ride (see: 9:02-9:20)

What exactly is "push the car higher" and "push the car higher back a day" really?
I looked it up but couldn't a find a meaning.

That’s not car higher, but car hire, which in American English would be called “renting a car.”
So push the car hire back a day means postpone picking up the rental car. In other words, shave one day off the car reservation.

(Or we would call it "the car rental".)

I think this is a case of the automatic captioning being trained on American English and not understanding a UK English phrase.
